# Swift 2.0 calendar components error

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

Hi I get this error in swift 2.0

Cannot invoke 'components' with an argument list of type '(NSCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate?, toDate: NSDate?, options: nil)'

```
var hoy = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        var despues = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(fecha)
        var calHoy = dataFormatter.dateFromString(hoy)
        var calcDesp = dataFormatter.dateFromString(despues)
        let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let unit:NSCalendarUnit = .Day
        let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: calcDesp, toDate: calHoy, options: nil)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As of Swift 2, `NS_OPTIONS` (such as `NSCalendarOptions`) are mapped to Swift as a `OptionSetType`
which offers a set-like interface. In particular, "no options" 
can now be specified as `[]` instead of `nil`:

```
let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: calcDesp!, toDate: calHoy!,
                               options: [])
```

See also [Swift 2.0 - Binary Operator "|" cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype)
and the recently added answers to [How to create NS_OPTIONS-style bitmask enumerations in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/swift-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass nil as your options argument. Use an empty option set instead:

```
let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: calcDesp!, toDate: calHoy!, options: [])
```

You also have to make sure to unwrap calcDesp and calHoy.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `rawValue` like the following :

`cal.components(unit, fromDate: calcDesp!, toDate: calHoy!, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))`