# Swift 2.0 constraintsWithVisualFormat

Tags: swift, autolayout, swift2

I have strange problem with AutoLayout in Swift 2.0

```
self.webView = WKWebView()
self.view.addSubview(self.webView!)

var viewBindingsDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
viewBindingsDict.setValue(self.webView, forKey: "webView")

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: 0, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[webView]|", options: 0, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
```

And I'm receiving error:

```
'String' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

for **"H:|[webView]|"** and **"V:|[webView]|"**

I do not know if im missing something

Update:
[image: Screenshot from playground]

Comment: Have you tried using plain `Dictionary` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`? Like `let viewBindingsDict = ["webView" : self.webView!]` ?

Comment: Also, I believe `addConstraints` may not like the fact, that the `webView` in the `NSMutableDictionary` is optional.

Comment: Michal I'm tried with Dictionary with same result. Look at screenshot, Xcode is pointed at "H:|[webView]|" as problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should change your `viewBindigsDict` to

```
var viewBindingsDict = [String: AnyObject]()
viewBindingsDict["webView"] = webView
```

as suggested in the comments, and also in the format options, you cannot use 0, instead:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
```

or more simplier as @MartinR suggested:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[webView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict))
```

Comment: Or just `options: []`, similar to (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30769477/1187415.