# NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat pass nil in options parameter in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

So I have a project, and UI in the project is completely coded (no .xib files or storyboards at all).
With Objective-C, we could pass `nil` or `0` as an argument for `options` parameter. Like this

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[one(two)]-[two(three)]-[three]-|" options: nil metrics:metrics views:views]];
```

**Swift 1.2 also allowed us to pass nil as an argument**

```
  self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[categoryTitleLabel]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

But in latest Xcode 7 beta 6 with Swift 2.0 options parameter now requires non-optional value, and I'm a little bit stuck.
I assumed, that earlier, if we passed `nil` in `options` parameter, then some default value from `NSLayoutFormatOptions` is used. I looked at `NSLayoutFormatOptions` declaration and found that `DirectionLeadingToTrailing` is the default value. So I replaced all nil arguments as `.DirectionLeadingToTrailing` . It worked, but the app started to crash with

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A constraint cannot be made between a leading/trailing attribute and a right/left attribute. Use leading/trailing for both or neither

I have realised that some constraints are conflicting, but the fact is that apparently, `.DirectionLeadingToTrailing` is not the default value. If not, then what is? Current workaround is passing `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)` as an argument but it looks ugly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift 2.0 constraintsWithVisualFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648444/swift-2-0-constraintswithvisualformat)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[categoryTitleLabel]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```