# Swift 2: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
class Example: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

var aView : UIView!

UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

       self.aView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity //This line is throwing the error mentioned in the Title


            }, completion: { finished in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
      })


}
```

This was working in earlier version of Swift but failing in version 2 not sure why

Comment: where did you define duration???

Comment: let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

Comment: Same problem (and solution) as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769387/swift-2-0-calendar-components-error (and the error message is completely misleading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to change

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
  delay: 0.0,
  usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
  initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
  options: nil,
  animations: {
```

with:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(duration,
  delay: 0.0,
  usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8,
  initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
  options: [],
  animations: {
```

There is just the "options" to change.