# Swift 2.0: Cannot convert NSDateComponents to NSCalendarUnit

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

Here is the line of code that receives the issue code:

```
let CompetitionDayDifference = userCalendar.components (dayCalendarUnit, fromDate: currentDate!, toDate: competitionDay, options: nil)
```

Issue code:

> Cannot convert value of type NSDateComponents to expected argument
>   type NSCalendarUnit

Additional code:

```
let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()


let competitionDate = NSDateComponents()
competitionDate.year = 2015
competitionDate.month = 6
competitionDate.day = 21
competitionDate.hour = 08
competitionDate.minute = 00
let competitionDay = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(competitionDate)!


// Here we compare the two dates
competitionDay.timeIntervalSinceDate(currentDate!)


let dayCalendarUnit = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: date)

//here we change the seconds to hours,minutes and days
let CompetitionDayDifference = userCalendar.components (dayCalendarUnit, fromDate: currentDate!, toDate: competitionDay, options: [])
```

Comment: You may need to include the whole line of code and the declaration/definition statements for the variables you use if you want someone to help you.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Swift 2.0 calendar components error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769387/swift-2-0-calendar-components-error).

Comment: @MartinR He also appears to be passing the wrong type for the first parameter (in addition to the options problem)

Comment: By the way, if your intent to show this elapsed time to the end-user, you can bypass some of this stuff and go directly to `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, For example `let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter();
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full;
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute];
let string = formatter.stringFromDate(firstDate, toDate: secondDate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, your `dayCalendarUnit` is a variable of type NSDateComponents.  You should be passing an `NSCalendarUnit` instead.  You also cannot pass `nil` for the options parameter as of Swift 2.0, so you would need to pass an empty option set:

```
let CompetitionDayDifference = userCalendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: currentDate!, toDate: competitionDay, options: [])
```