# NSDateComponents.setValue() not working with iOS 7 and lower version

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I needed to add one year to the current date (swift & iOS 7 and above). But every solutions i have found is only support iOS 8 and above. Please guide me through proper solution.
Thanks

```
 let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Year);
    let date: NSDate = NSDate()
    let expirationDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setValue()` method of `NSDateComponents` is only available on
iOS 8/OS X 10.9 or later:

```
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Year)
```

For iOS 7 support, simply use

```
components.year = 1
```

Also note that

```
dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)
```

can be written shorter as

```
dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: [])
```

compare for example [Swift 2.0 calendar components error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769387/swift-2-0-calendar-components-error).