# Swift 2/Xcode 7 beta - multiple bitmasks produce error

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

Im creating a UIView animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1,
    delay: 0,
    options: (.AllowUserInteraction | .Repeat | .Autoreverse),
    animations:
        { () -> Void in

            // Animate

    },
    completion: nil)
```

But the compiler says “Could not find member “Autoreverse””, or whichever bit mask is on the end, unless there is one option. Has the syntax changed in Swift 2? I can’t see anything in the Swift docs nor do I remember anything in the WWDC presentations.

Or could it possibly just be a bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

Answer found here:

[Swift 2.0 - Binary Operator "|" cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype)

“In Swift 2 the syntax has been updated..”

To cut it short, instead of

```
.Type | .Another | .Third
```

Use

```
[.Type, .Another, .Third]
```