# Swift: Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two NSCalendarUnit operands (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode7-beta2

Why I can't use `|` Binary operator in `calendar.components` to separate the units? According to this article by [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/) or this Github project by [minorbug](https://gist.github.com/minorbug/468790060810e0d29545) I should be allowed to do it.

**Code:**

```
calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.Month | NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: date)
```

Answers I find in [Apple Community](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3623):
But Xcode 7 don't allow me to use `NSDateComponentsFormatter()` for `componentsUnits`.

**Concerns:**
This might be Xcode 7 cause someone says this is fine in Xcode 6, does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Essentially the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30761996/1630618.  Use `calendar.components([.Month, .Day], fromData: data)`.

Comment: @vacawama Interesting, this work for me, please write answer.