# Piping NSEventMask together in 'addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask'

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsevent

I have the following code for listening for mouse events outside the view (subclass of NSView). This works great as it is, but I cannot figure out how to pipe the NSEventMasks together. I basically want to have the same event listener fire on `NSEventMask.LeftMouseDownMask`, `NSEventMask.RightMouseDownMask` and `NSEventMask.OtherMouseDownMask`.

Does anyone know how to pipe them together or if it's even possible in Swift?

**Working code**

```
localMouseEventListener = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDownMask) { (event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent? in

        // Event handling...

        return event
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763344/4063602) might help you.

In short you can now use arrays, so this seems to make the compiler happy:

```
localMouseEventListener = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask([.LeftMouseDownMask, .RightMouseDownMask, .OtherMouseDownMask]) { (event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent? in

    // Event handling...

    return event
}
```

Comment: Indeed the compiler is happy :-)