# Swift 3.0 Syntax change for UIUserNotificationSettings

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am using swift 3.0 and am trying to add badge numbers to my app. I believe the correct way to do this is similar to what is below.

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
            UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil
            ))

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
```

However, I get an error for using '|' in `UIUserNotificationSettings` block and will also receive the error "Argument labels (forTypes, categories) do not match any of the available overloads" for `UIUserNotificationSettings` if I only have `UIUserNotificationType.badge` as the first argument. Did swift 3.0 change the syntax for this statement?

Comment: *All* syntax changed with Swift 3, but yours is even pre-Swift 2. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30763344/1187415 and then start the "Convert to current Swift Syntax" converter in Xcode. Or read the documentation.

Comment: I couldn't care less about the points, but you should change the correct answer for this question as it changed with iOS 10.0. It's a very common question, and people should know what the correct answer is for now,

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It has been updated in both Swift 2 and Swift 3. This line should fix your issue. Also make sure any other lines with UIUserNotificationType have had their variables switched to lowercase.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
```

Comment: Swift 3 + iOS 10 uses UNNotificationSettings https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings

Comment: `UIUserNotificationSettings` has now been deprecated for iOS 10.0. I posted an answer below as to what's the current recommended syntax.

Answer (score 15):

From what I understand, `UIUserNotificationSettings` has been deprecated for iOS 10.0. It is now recommended that you use the `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

Here's what I did to make sure my code was up to date:

1) Import the `UserNotifications` framework in your `AppDelegate`

`import UserNotifications`

2) Inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function inside the `AppDelegate`, add the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

        if granted {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

Once you have the notifications registered and allowed, you can change the badge number at any point:

`UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = value`

This worked for me, I just tested it by sending a remote notification to my phone, and it worked fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

"rawValue" can use | operator.

This code works in swift3, we don't need to do that though.

```
let types = UIUserNotificationType(rawValue:UIUserNotificationType.alert.rawValue | UIUserNotificationType.sound.rawValue | UIUserNotificationType.badge.rawValue)

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil))
```